# Resources on mesh networks

Tags: networking, p2p, mesh-network

Does anyone have any pointers to good resources concerning mesh networks?

Maybe I'm not even using the correct terminology. I need to write an app that has multiple agents on various machines, and each agent must have knowledge of and be able to communicate with others. A type of P2P application perhaps?

I'm really looking for some architecture-level stuff to get me started on the planning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're talking about writing a [multi-agent system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-agent_system). What language are you using? [Jade](http://jade.tilab.com/) is an example of a mature agent communication framework for Java. The basic idea is that you give your agents 'behaviours', and these are triggered when particularly events are notified. Jade provides a [publish/subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe) framework for sending and receiving such messages.

Note that your agents don't have to implement advanced AI algorithms or anything like that. They can be simple producers and consumers of data if that suits your problem.

Comment: I'm using C#, but no reason why I can't use Java for the base 'agent' stuff, and build the C# app on top of that. I hadn't encountered Jade before. Looks promising. Thanks!