# Android mesh networking

Tags: android, networking, esp8266, mesh-network

I am about to make an application that uses *mesh networking* for communication. I have found [The Serval Project](http://www.servalproject.org/) so far, but the problem is that I do not understand the complete logic behind mesh networking.

What I know is the *mesh* is a centralized communication protocol.

The idea is to make an Android app that uses mesh networking and ESP8266 microcontroller also uses mesh networking.

The problem is that there are not enough resources for this. Can you please help me to accomplish this task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mesh networks resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339812/mesh-networks-resources)

Answer (score 3):

There are apps like that for Android. Beside Serval look for Manet, Firechat, or BC Mesh.
They mostly use Bluetooth and tend to draw a lot of current from the battery. As soon as the WLAN and ad-hoc networking shall be used, the Android must be rooted, which is not liked by all users.

BTW, a good mesh networking protocol is not centralized to prevent a mesh breakdown when the central node fails.